# How to check for the existence of a text value

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I am very much new to Robot Framework

I need to check for the existence of "Logout" button in the webpage.

```
<button type="button" class="ant-btn" style="width: 80px; float: right; display: inline-block;"><span>Logout</span></button>
```

I have declared variables like
*** Variables ***

```
${logout_path}     xpath=//*/button[@class='ant-btn']/span

${l_path}      xpath=(//*/span[contains(text(),"Logout")])
```

and under *** Test Cases ***

```
Get Element Attribute  xpath=(//*/button[@class='ant-btn']/span)

Element Text Should be ${logout_path}  'Logout'
```

All the above syntax tested and FAILED.

How to check if this text 'Logout' is present in the Webpage,
All I need is to check for the existence of this field.

Kindly help with syntax.

Thank you :)

Comment: Few thoughts: 1. In first line you do not obtain any element attribute and I think this is root cause of error. 2. In second line you are comparing xpath that already contains expression to check text, so from my point of view it has little sense. You could you use keyword `Page Should Contain`.

Comment: Thank you. I added Page Should Contain  ${l_path} and it returned "Page should have contained text 'xpath=(//*/span[contains(text(),"Logout")])' but did not"

Comment: I was able to fix this issue. Used Page Should Contain followed by Sleep command and solved the problem.Thanks @JaPyR

Answer (score 1):

```
Element Text Should Be    ${logout_path}    Logout
```

for more info see:
http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Element%20Text%20Should%20Be